# Is there away to get a checkbox checked status

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have check boxes that are created by code depending on a database result.

```cs
var checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
var checkBoxes = new CheckBox[0];
//in a for loop I have
checkBox.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
line view.AddView(checkBox);
Array.Resize(ref checkBoxes, i + 1);
CheckBoxes[i] = checkBox;
```

All works, I get my checkBoxes that contain a all the name tables from the database so I have 4 tables I get 4 checkboxes

The issue is I'm not sure on the best way to check if its checked.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin/Android, but most other .NET CheckBox classes have a boolean `Checked` property (true if the checkbox is checked, false otherwise)

Comment: Tried if statement to check if the checkBox.Checked and Al's tried checking if it's TRUE, however seams the if statement has no affect but thank you for the response

Comment: By the way, creating an array of zero length and then resizing it in a loop is not very efficient at all.  If you have a `for` loop like `for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i)` to process a loop, all you should be doing is creating a loop for `N` elements to start with: `var checkBoxes = new CheckBox[N];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tried if statement to check if the checkBox.Checked and Al's tried
> checking if it's TRUE, however seams the if statement has no affect

Have you assigned value `true` for your checkBox's property `Checked`?

If you didn't do this,then the value of the `checkBox.Checked` will be the default value `false`.

You can refer to the following code,I tested on my side, it works properly.

```
        var layout_main = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent
        );
        layout_main.LayoutParameters = p2;
        layout_main.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

       LinearLayout.LayoutParams param_btn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        param_btn.SetMargins(0,500,0,0);
        var myBtn = new Button(this);
        myBtn.LayoutParameters = param_btn;
        myBtn.Text = "chang text";
        myBtn.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param_checkbox = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        param_btn.SetMargins(0, 100, 0, 0);
        var checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.LayoutParameters = param_checkbox;
        checkBox.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;

        checkBox.Text = "test";
        checkBox.Checked = true;



        myBtn.Click += delegate {

            if (checkBox.Checked)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "---> checkBox's checked = " + checkBox.Checked, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

        };

        layout_main.AddView(myBtn);

        layout_main.AddView(checkBox);
```

Comment: That's greate, I forgot the delegate method adding that solved this thank you for taking the time

Comment: @OhNo: Adding the `delegate` shouldn't have solved your problem.  You only need an `OnChecked` handler if you want to track when a checkbox is checked on or checked off.  You can read its state anytime